# is there a Font color in pygame?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I have used the font woodcut medium in my fonts folder its the folder windows
makes (C:\Windows\Fonts) and the color of it is not in pygame is there like a way to
make it use the font color in the font
edit: my font is at C:\Windows\Fonts\woodcut.ttf
edit: here's the font [the font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX6VP.png)

Comment: Please include the code ([mre]). You should be able to pass in a color when you `render` the font.

Comment: What makes you say the color is not in pygame? Can you show us the color?

Comment: @JoboFernandez i dont know how

Comment: @julievaldez is it not a plain color having its own rgb or hex value?

Comment: @JoboFernandez yes

Comment: @JoboFernandez yes it is two colors

Comment: May not be very helpful, but does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825207/multi-colored-text-in-pygame) answer your question?

Comment: @JoboFernandez i edited my post too see if that helps you get an idea

Comment: Have you tried using sysfont? ```pygame.font.SysFont(name, size, bold=False, italic=False)```. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont. Then use render after that.

Comment: @JoboFernandez ima try that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sysfont? pygame.font.SysFont(name, size, bold=False, italic=False). pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont. Then use render after that. –
Jobo Fernandez
ansererd correct